# XML layout has a ListView - But still getting ListView id not found exception

Tags: android

I see a lot of questions being asked in the stackoverflow on the same topic, but i `could not understand the deep problem` of the exception.

Below is my XML layout. I have a listView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#656565"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" 
        android:dividerHeight="20.0sp"
        android:divider="#656565"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is my Fragment class.

```
public class FragmentClass extends SherlockListFragment implements AsyncListner{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.documents, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    }

      @Override
      public void onLoadComplete(List<DocumentResponse> data) {           
          DocumentsAdapter adapter = new DocumentsAdapter(getSherlockActivity(),
                    R.id.list, data);
          setListAdapter(adapter);
      }

}
```

Once the onLoadComplete call is finished, i am trying to create my ListView. But i get this error. "**Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is android.R.id.list**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `android:id="@+id/list"` to `android:id="@android:id/list"`

With this you are using the requested `android.R.id.list` id.

Don't forget to update the code, too

```
DocumentsAdapter adapter = new DocumentsAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), android.R.id.list, data);
```

Comment: How come this would solve the issue and why is mine throwing an error.

Comment: Because your `id.list` has a different value and android checks if there is a listview in the layout by searching for a predefined value: `android.R.id.list`. So you just need to reuse the already generated id from android.